# Communication between parent and child process - Perl

Tags: perl, tcl, fork, exec, system

I'm running a perl program "a.pl" in the terminal that needs to call another program "b.pl" which then turns the environment to a tcl shell. The program "b.pl" sets environment variables which I have to use back in the main program "a.pl", after which I need to run new commands in the tcl environment created by "b.pl". Please see the example below

Program: **a.pl**

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    #turns it to a tcl shell and sets environment variable VERSION
    system ("./b.pl");

    system ("source <tclExecutable> -version $VERSION");
```

The second system command doesn't execute until I exit the tcl shell manually in the terminal. I've looked at fork and opening a pipe but I'm not sure how to go about it. I need to execute the second command in the tcl shell opened by the first system command. How can I make this work?

Comment: You can't set a parent's environment variables in a child process.

Comment: *How* does b.pl set env vars?

Comment: That's quite the oddest way of running a Tcl script I've seen. Well, this week anyway…

Comment: you may want to try sockets for communicating.. another simple solution could be just write out the information from b.pl into a text file, process it in a.pl before running tcl shell

Answer (score 0):

You may run `b.pl` "inside" a.pl using `require`.  It may deliver what you want for simple scripts.

a.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $Version;
require "/.../b.pl"; # full path to b.pl script
print "Version: $Version\n";
```

b.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $Version;
$Version = "YES!";
```